# 2d array realloc Segmentation Fault Error

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array, realloc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void Append(int **arr, int *count, int *len, int x, int y){
    if (*count >= *len){
        *len *= 2;
        arr = realloc(arr, *len * sizeof(int*));
        for (int i=*count; i< *len; ++i){
            arr[i] = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);
        }
    }
    arr[*count][0] = x;
    arr[*count][1] = y;
    ++*count;
}


int main(){
    int **arr, count, len;

    arr = (int **) malloc(sizeof(int *) * 1);
    arr[0] = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);

    count = 0;
    len = 1;

    for (int i=0; i<100; ++i){
        Append(arr, &count, &len, i, i);
        printf("%d - %d %d\n", i, arr[i][0], arr[i][1]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**OUT**

```
0 - 0 0
1 - 1 1
Segmentation Fault
```

I have such a code and I get an error like above. I could not find where the problem originated. Can you help?

**When I change the code as below, I don't get any error and the code works properly.**
what is the difference between these two?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct{
    int **arr;
    int len;
    int count;
}ARRAY;

void Append(ARRAY *array, int x, int y){
    if (array->count >= array->len){
        array->len *= 2;
        array->arr = realloc(array->arr, array->len * sizeof(int *));
        for (int i=array->count; i< array->len; ++i){
            array->arr[i] = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);
        }
    }
    array->arr[array->count][0] = x;
    array->arr[array->count][1] = y;
    ++array->count;
}

int main(){
    ARRAY coordinate;

    coordinate.arr = (int **) malloc(sizeof(int *) * 1);
    coordinate.arr[0] = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);

    coordinate.len = 1;
    coordinate.count = 0;

    for (int i=0; i<100; ++i){
        Append(&coordinate, i, i);
        printf("%d - %d %d\n", i, coordinate.arr[i][0], coordinate.arr[i][1]);
    }



    return 0;
}
```

........................................................................................

Comment: When you `arr = realloc(arr,...)` in the function, it doesn't change the `arr` pointer in `main`. So the pointer always points to the original memory that `malloc` returned.

Comment: in your original code, the parameter `arr` is a double pointer but your references to where that parameter points is failing to dereference those accesses, resulting the code referencing the parameter in the call stack rather than the data in `main()`

Comment: OT: a call to `malloc()` returns a `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer therefore should not cast the returned value as that just clutters the code and is error prone.

Comment: OT: the call to `realloc()` can fail.  Therefore, should always assign the returned value to a temp pointer, check the temp pointer for not NULL and if not NULL then assign the temp pointer to the target pointer.  Otherwise when the call fails, the target pointer will be set to NULL, resulting in the allocated memory being lost, resulting in a memory leak

Comment: OT: when returning from `main()`, for robust code, all those memory allocations should be passed to `free()`

Comment: @user3386109 I do not agree with your comment. Because when I first allocate the array its size is 1. If you look at the OUT output, there are 2 items suppressed. so realloc worked once. I don't know what you're talking about because I learned C from the internet. Please don't misunderstand my comment.

Comment: @FishTuna When you call `realloc`, there are two things that can happen. 1) The pointer returned by `realloc` is the same as the pointer that you passed. In this case the original `malloc` allocated more memory than you requested, so `realloc` basically just gave you permission to use that memory. 2) The pointer returned by `realloc` is different than the pointer that you passed. In this case, `realloc` calls `malloc` to get a new chunk of memory, and then copies the old data into the new memory. So if `realloc` appeared to work once, it's because it didn't change the address the first time.

Answer (score 1):

`realloc()` function is quite complex in detail. It works different from time to time. For example, let's say you allocated an array which contains two `int`s using `malloc()`, and call `realloc()` to grow its size.

```
int *arr;

arr = malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);
arr = realloc(arr, sizeof(int) * 5);
```

Sometimes, `realloc()` will only grow its size. But sometimes, it will work as you wrote like this:

```
int *arr;

arr = malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);

int *new;

new = malloc(sizeof(int) * 5);
memcpy(new, arr, 2); //copy first 2 elements of arr to new
free(arr);
arr = new;
```

It means that `realloc()` will sometimes change `arr`'s value.

```
int *arr1;
int *arr2;

arr1 = malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);
arr2 = realloc(arr1, sizeof(int) * 5);

if (arr1 == arr2)
    printf("not changed\n");
else
    printf("changed\n");
```

So above code will sometimes print "not changed", and sometimes print "changed" (I'm not sure about that the exact same code will reproduce different results. What I can say safely is that the result will be different depends on the new size that you sent to `realloc()`).

So the reason why your first code generates two items is because `realloc()` doesn't change `arr`'s value on first few calls, and changed the value after that. But as user3629249 mentioned on comment, what `realloc()` changed is the local variable `arr`, not the `arr` from `main()`. Then your next attempt to access memory space that `arr` points to, such as `arr[i][0]`, must cause segmentation fault, because the memory space that `arr` is pointing to is already freed.

Sorry for any grammar errors. I'm not native English user.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not related to `realloc` but to something very fundemental for C programming.

In C when you pass a variable to a function it's **the value of the variable** which is passed and **saved in a new variable**. A consequence of that is that you can not change the value of the passed variable.

Simple example:

```
void foo(int x)
{
    printf("%d\n", x);  // Will print 42
    x = 5;
    printf("%d\n", x);  // Will print 5
}

void bar()
{
    int x = 42;
    printf("%d\n", x);  // Will print 42
    foo(x);
    printf("%d\n", x);  // Will still print 42 because foo can't change this x
}
```

The `x` in `bar` and the `x` in `foo` are **two different variables** so changing `x` if `foo` does not change `x` in `bar`.

This is exactly the problem with your first code example. The variable `arr` in `main` **will not change** by the assignment `arr = realloc(...`.

In order to change the value of `arr` in `main` inside the function, you must pass a **pointer to `arr`**, i.e. `Append(&arr, ...`

Now you are a three star programmer.

Using the simple example again:

```
void foo(int* x)
{
    printf("%d\n", *x);  // Will print 42
    *x = 5;
    printf("%d\n", *x);  // Will print 5
}

void bar()
{
    int x = 42;
    printf("%d\n", x);  // Will print 42
    foo(&x);            // Pass the address of x
    printf("%d\n", x);  // Will print 5 because foo changed this x
}
```

Now `foo` can change the value of `x` in `bar` because `foo` is passed the address of `x`.

And that is exactly what you do in your second code example, i.e. you only make change to values **pointed to** by `array` which is `coordinate` in `main`.