# Realloc + memcpy 2D float array results in segmentation fault

Tags: c, struct, undefined-behavior, realloc

I made a structure (SomeMisc) which has a float array, so I can fill it with some values, and then try to memcpy its float array to a different struct's float array, and print out the result to see if it worked.

The other structure (ArrayPairs) is supposed to hold two arrays of arrays. So that low[i] belongs to high[i] and vice versa when I want to make some changes on "a couple".

So I make 2 SomeMisc objects, fill their arrays with numbers, and then try to make a function where I expand the low-array and high-array of the ArrayPairs object with realloc firstly, then I try to malloc space to the new rows, and then finally memcpy content from the 2 SomeMisc member arrays given as arguments to the function.

But it keeps resulting in segmentation faults and/or undefined behavior, and I can't figure out why.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct some{
  int32_t len;
  float* arr;
} SomeMisc;

typedef struct arrPrs{
  int32_t amountOfRows;
  int32_t amountOfColumns;
  float** low;
  float** high;
} ArrayPairs;

void initializeArrayPairArray(ArrayPairs* AP, int32_t length, int32_t width){

  AP->amountOfRows = length;
  AP->amountOfColumns = width;

  AP->low = (float**)malloc(length * sizeof(float*));
  AP->high = (float**)malloc(length * sizeof(float*));

  for(int i=0; i<length; i++){
    AP->low[i] = (float*)malloc(width * sizeof(float));
    AP->high[i] = (float*)malloc(width * sizeof(float));
    for(int j=0; j<width; j++){
      AP->low[i][j] = 32;
      AP->high[i][j] = 44;
    }
  }
}

void addArrayPair(ArrayPairs* AP, float* low, float* high){
  AP->amountOfRows++;

  AP->low = (float**)realloc(AP->low, AP->amountOfRows * sizeof(float*));
  AP->high = (float**)realloc(AP->high, AP->amountOfRows * sizeof(float*));

  AP->low[AP->amountOfRows] = (float*)malloc(AP->amountOfColumns * sizeof(float));
  AP->high[AP->amountOfRows] = (float*)malloc(AP->amountOfColumns * sizeof(float));

  memcpy(AP->low[AP->amountOfRows], low, AP->amountOfColumns * sizeof(float));
  memcpy(AP->high[AP->amountOfRows], high, AP->amountOfColumns * sizeof(float));

  printf("TESTING PRINT: %.2f\n", AP->high[10][5]);
}

int main () {
  int32_t nrOfCols = 8;
  int32_t nrOfRows = 10;

  ArrayPairs arr;
  initializeArrayPairArray(&arr, nrOfRows, nrOfCols);

  int32_t mArrLength = 2;
  SomeMisc* mArr = (SomeMisc*)malloc(mArrLength*sizeof(SomeMisc));
  for(int i=0; i<mArrLength; i++){
    mArr[i].arr = (float*)malloc(nrOfCols*sizeof(float));
    for(int j=0; j<nrOfCols; j++){
      mArr[i].arr[j] = (i+1)*j;
    }
  }

  addArrayPair(&arr, mArr[0].arr, mArr[1].arr);

  printf("LOW:\tHIGH:\n");
  for(int i=9; i<arr.amountOfRows; i++){
    printf("INDEX: %d\n",i);
    for(int j=0; j<arr.amountOfColumns; j++){
      printf("%.2f\t%.2f\n",arr.low[i][j],arr.high[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }

  return(0);
}
```

I followed this answer: [2d array realloc Segmentation Fault Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68689640/2d-array-realloc-segmentation-fault-error)

But I already have the `ArrayPairs* AP` in the parameter list of `addArrayPair`, and the `&` with the object `arr` when calling the function.

I also tried dereferencing as was suggested in that answer, but this didn't work either:

```
void addArrayPair(ArrayPairs* AP, float* low, float* high){
  (*AP).amountOfRows++;

  (*AP).low = (float**)realloc((*AP).low, AP->amountOfRows * sizeof(float*));
  (*AP).high = (float**)realloc((*AP).high, AP->amountOfRows * sizeof(float*));

  (*AP).low[AP->amountOfRows] = (float*)malloc((*AP).amountOfColumns * sizeof(float));
  (*AP).high[AP->amountOfRows] = (float*)malloc((*AP).amountOfColumns * sizeof(float));

  memcpy((*AP).low[(*AP).amountOfRows], low, (*AP).amountOfColumns * sizeof(float));
  memcpy((*AP).high[(*AP).amountOfRows], high, (*AP).amountOfColumns * sizeof(float));
}
```

Comment: Note that the "arrow" operator `->` implies pointer dereference. `AP->amountOfRows` and `(*AP).amountOfRows` is the exact same thing.

Comment: @user326964 Aside: Consider `AP->low = (float**)malloc(length * sizeof(float*));` obliges a review to search for `ArrayPairs* AP` and then `typedef struct arrPrs{ ...   float** low;... } ArrayPairs;` to see if the type was right.  Instead use `AP->low = malloc(sizeof AP->low[0] * length);`.  It is easier to code right, review and maintain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You increase `AP->amountOfRows` too early. That means when you do `AP->low[AP->amountOfRows]` you will use an out-of-bounds index, and have *undefined behavior*

Instead (re)allocate `AP->amountOfRows + 1` elements, and increase `AP->amountOfRows` once all allocations and copying is done:

```
void addArrayPair(ArrayPairs* AP, float* low, float* high){
  AP->low = realloc(AP->low, (AP->amountOfRows + 1) * sizeof(float*));
  AP->high = realloc(AP->high, (AP->amountOfRows + 1) * sizeof(float*));

  AP->low[AP->amountOfRows] = malloc(AP->amountOfColumns * sizeof(float));
  AP->high[AP->amountOfRows] = malloc(AP->amountOfColumns * sizeof(float));

  memcpy(AP->low[AP->amountOfRows], low, AP->amountOfColumns * sizeof(float));
  memcpy(AP->high[AP->amountOfRows], high, AP->amountOfColumns * sizeof(float));

  // Increase once all is done
  AP->amountOfRows++;
}
```

Comment: Holy macaroni, I can't believe you of all people answered my question. You're like a celebrity here! Problem solved! Very simple explanation too. Just waiting for the 8 minutes to pass so I can accept the answer. Thank you so much!

Comment: @user326964 Well, Some Dude is not only a very knowledgeable but also a very active user who helps a lot; his rating reflects this combination.